# Java connect to mysql on android application

Tags: java, mysql, database, exception

I'm trying to connect to mysql database from my android application, but all times I try to connect it give me this: Could not create connection to '  .  '

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText));
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/db_name","root","password");
        text.setText(R.string.connected);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        text.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I tried to commend bind-address in mysql settings to allow connect from other services, but it still throw this error.

Comment: can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: 1) is `ip` reachable from the phone e.g. if you install a terminal app on the phone and will try connecting to that ip and port - will that connect you to something? 2) is that an emulator / phone? 3) are you able to connect to mysql from any other node than the one where mysql is installed?

tangential: anyone having the app can decompile the code and access your db